# 0 mayor que NULL PHP

Tags: php, web, aplicación-web, comparaciones

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la siguiente condición me dé como resultado verdadero?

```
$variable = null;
$variable_2 = 0;
if($variable < $variable_2){
    Do_something();
}
```

El problema es que aparentemente 0(Int) es lo mismo que NULL para el intérprete de PHP
Pero necesito que distinga la "diferencia"
¿Se les ocurre alguna forma de hacer eso?

Comment: Por favor podrías explicar cual es el objetivo de comparar un null con un int?.Tendría sentido que compares dos numeros int.

Comment: Estoy construyendo como un "filtro"  de una array entonces los valores que ya no se tomaran en cuenta los pongo en null y se va comparando con otros int para evaluar cual es mayor, de cero hacia arriba no hay problema, pero cuando es 0 si.

Comment: Ahorita que mencionas eso, se me ocurrio la idea de asignar un valor negativo en vez de null y hacer la comparacion, creo que no daria problema porque en la institucion no se daria el escenario de que tenga un valor en - .
Y asi 0 seria mayor que -1 por ejemplo

Comment: Correcto eso sería mas lógico, o podrías eliminar directamente esos elementos del array, ya que no los vas a tomar en cuenta posteriormente para tu condición.

Comment: Gracias @mhplur por tu ayuda, comentaré que pasa con la solución pensada

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
$variable = null;
$variable_2 = 0;
if(!isset($variable) || $variable < $variable_2){
    Do_something();
}
```